# Which plupload runtimes for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, plupload

[plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) allows different runtime technology to do file uploading.

Although it lists some browser incompatibilities for HTML 5, it doesn't appear to answer the basic question of which browser has this runtime available at all.

Which browsers will not support plupload's HTML 5 runtime?

`plupload` allows you to customize the list of runtimes and the order in which to try them. I'd like to insure that, given the restricted lists of browser I need to support, that I can rely on a subset of runtimes. Supporting Flash, for instance, can be difficult, so I'd like to know if I need to include it and support it.

Comment: From the main header on that page... "Allows you to upload files using HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms..." thus I presume the tool uses the best capabilities available... e.g. if you have Flash, it might use flash...

Comment: @scunliffe: question edited

Comment: IE<=9 will not support HTML5 runtime (haven't tried IE10 so far). I've been using "html5,flash,gears,silverlight,browserplus" sequence with no real problem ( flash seems to be tricky with httpOnly browser cookies ) Never tried over https

Answer (score 8):

A basic answer and relatively subjective answer is:

I stopped considering the runtimes `gears`, `silverlight` and `browserplus`.

In terms of functionalities, `HTML5` > `Flash` > `HTML4`.

Finally:

- IE 10 supports HTML5
- IE 8/9 supports Flash (if it is installed), otherwise the basic denominator is HTML4.

This means I had to test for five scenario.

I found support for all these runtimes to be approximative in case the elements are hidden or moved and in different ways. For instance in one case, initializing `plupload` early worked for IE 10/HTML5 and IE 8/9/HTML4 but not for Flash, while initializing later worked only for IE 8/9/Flash and not the other cases. It was difficult to isolate basic conditions, I could only open [this issue](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/788).

I have yet to encounter any such problem with any runtime in any other browser.

Hope this helps somebody.